# Installing the python packages in virtual enviroment with sudo

Tags: python, mysql, virtualenv

Actually I came across the problem while trying to install mySQL on a Django development virtual environment.

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

I tried running `sudo pip install mysqlclient`. It runs well, but the package gets installed on the global environment. I thought it might require super-user permission to do that. Is there a way to install it on virtual-environment?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: What operating system are you using? You should not need `sudo` to install packages for Python, especially in a virtual environment.

Comment: I'm using linux mint. I tried running command sudo pip install mysqlclient. It works well but gets installed on global environment.

Comment: Use `pip install --user …` to use a local directory. Or use Pyenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) to get a local Python installation where you can use `pip` without `sudo`.

Comment: Sorry to say that i'm a bit new to linux, can't get what you mean, i viewed the link provided by you, it seems a bit difficult for me to understand.

Comment: Does `pip install --user …` work?

Comment: Din't worked!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i forgot to mention the python version which i was using 3.6.7. I somehow managed to install the package on the python 3.5.6. Follow the sequence if you're having the same problem.

Install the additional support repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
```

Run update:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Install python 3.5(which works in my case):

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5
```

Install python3.5 dev

```
sudo apt-get install python3.5-dev
```

Create a virtual-enviroment with python3.5 and perform

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

And fortunately that works well!! Boom!!!